# Single entry Schengen visa, destination added

Tags: schengen-visas, pakistani-citizens

I intend to travel to Paris (2 days) and then to Zurich (2 days) for a conference from Islamabad Pakistan.
My initial itinerary included entry from Paris and exit from Zurich. I have been granted 15 days single entry Schengen visa from French embassy.

Now I intend to travel to my sisters place in Munich for 2 days after stay in Zurich and also now I will travel back to Islamabad from Munich (itinerary submitted at French embassy shows I will travel back from Zurich). My total time in the Schengen area will be 6 days.
So will that effect me in any way.

Comment: Does your 15 day visa allow you enough time for your amended plan?

Comment: yes.plan is of total 06 days stay.02 days each in france,switzerland and germany

Answer (score 4):

- It is common for Schengen visa to grant both extra days and some flexibility in the dates, so that you won't need a new visa just because a meeting is re-scheduled by a few days. Check that the extension fits on both criteria, both the changed entry/exit date and the changed total days.
  **Be careful -- you have a first date of entry, a last date of exit, and a maximum number of *full or partial* days. You might not be allowed to use both the earliest possible entry and the latest possible exit on the same trip.**
- You **may** adjust your itinerary with a Schengen visa after the visa is granted, as long as the main premise remains the same. If you do have your conference as planned, then adding a family visit does not change the main premise.
- You **must not** misrepresent your itinerary to get your visa, or to change which consulate is responsible for issuing it ('visa shopping').

So in theory, this is possible. In practice, you should take care that you do not **appear** to have misrepresented your itinerary, even if you did tell the truth.

- It is good that you arrive as planned, where planned, and go to the conference first. I expect you will have documentation on that.
- Both the new and the old itinerary would have been handled by France. So there can be no question of 'visa shopping.'
- It will be good if you have your departure booked, even if it isn't exactly as originally planned. Bring enough money for the extra days, even if you will stay with your sister, to avoid questions in that regard.
- It would be helpful if this isn't your first Schengen visit.

There should be no problem unless there is something about your application I don't know.

Comment: thanks a lot.much appreciated.